# Como popular em base de dados para realizar testes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou precisando popular este banco para realizar testes de consultas para cunho didáticos.

[image: Modelo OLPT]

Eu já possuo uns 5 alunos, 2 professores, mas o problema esta para popular os exercícios de forma manual. Existe alguma forma mais prática?

Comment: Thiago, a pergunta está muito vaga para dar uma resposta melhor, mas você poderia utilizar alguma linguagem de programação para criar uma rotina automática de inserção ou mesmo utilizar sites que criam sql através de dados de um Excel, por exemplo. Qual opção seria melhor para voce?

Comment: Então, pode ser em excel... não tem problema! Só precisava mesmo ter que popular o banco tipo com um loremipson da vida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom como voce mencionou o Excel. Existem sites na internet que transformam arquivos CSV em Scripts SQL prontos. Basta voce informar o arquivo e alguns parâmetros que ele pede.

Esse [site](https://sqlizer.io/#/)(SQLizer) faz isso muito bem já utilizei diversas vezes.

Como você comentou que é para fins didáticos tempo para transformar os dados não vai ser problema para você (acredito)

Basta possuir os arquivos no excel e o site gera o script pronto para carregar no SQL

[image: Exemplo de utilização]